# How to move an object from one place to another

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation

How do I make an object move from place a (x, y) to place b (x, y) in Xcode, preferably with Cocoa Touch.

Regards, Nikita.

Answer (score 2):

Use Core Animation blocks:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                 animations:^{ 
                   myView.frame = newFrame; 
                 } completion:^(BOOL  completed){
                   // done!
                 }];
```